# Graphing and filling an area based on 4 or 5 coordinate points using JavaScript or Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, coldfusion, raphael

Thanks for taking a look at my question. I'm trying to create a graph that will show the range of widths/heights that will fit within a container. The graphs will always be shaped in one of the two ways show below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIrO3.jpg
or
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGyU0.jpg

I know the x/y coordinates of the red corners of the object. There will always be either 4 or 5 points. I need to fill the area between the points as well. I was not able to make this work with Coldfusion's CFCHART, and haven't found a way with JavaScript. Does anyone know how this can be done? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to it with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). This library allows drawing of various shapes on the web pages using vector graphic.

Comment: Raphael does some neat things as far as drawing goes. I can draw the shape I need, but it looks like I'd need to find a way to position and scale the shape, and position the numbers on the graphs axis on my own, essentially building a graph with lines/numbers from scratch. It seems like there must be an easier way to do this, no? Thanks for your suggestion, your input is appreciated!

Comment: Actually the type of chart you want is very unusual. There are some number of visualization libraries but none of them have support for charts you want. However you can try highcharts or d3 if don't need support for IE6-8.

Comment: use raphael for the points and the shape, and a background image for the lines/marks. as for scaling and positioning, don't you know basic geometry/arithmetic? USE THE POWER OF MATH.

Comment: I ended up using Raphael. I used a background image for the graph lines, while dynamically adding the x/y values to the graph. Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Google Charts API?

Comment: I can't see any way of using Google charts to do what the questioner asks. If it will do so can you give an example?